# Django model with hundreds of fields

Tags: python, django

I have a model with hundreds of properties. The properties can be of different types (integer, strings, uploaded files, ...). I would like to implement this complex model step by step, starting with the most important properties. I can think of two options:

1. Define the properties as regular model fields
2. Define a separate model to hold each property separately, and link it to the main model with a `ForeignKey`

I have not found any suggestions on how to handle models with lots of properties with django. What are the advantages / drawbacks of both approaches?

Comment: in programming in general, if your class has hundreds of fields, it probably needs to be rethought (inheritance, separate classes etc)

Comment: @Sayse: customer requirement. I am definitely not going to rethink their architecture.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely should **not** define your properties as ForeignKeys. Every time you need a full model, your database server will have to make hundreds of `JOINs`, therefore ruining your performance.

If your properties are needed almost every time you access the model, you should keep them in the same model. If not, you could make a separate `Properties` model and link it to your original model via `OneToOneField`.

I personally had such an experience. We had to build a hotel recomendation engine, and we were using [Drupal](http://drupal.org) back then. And as Drupal stores every custom property in a separate MySQL table, we quickly realised we should switch the framework, because every single query crashed our production servers (20+ JOINs are a deadly thing to MySQL). BTW, we ended up using a custom solution based on [ElasticSearch](http://elastic.co), which handles hundreds of fields just fine.

**Update**: If you're lucky enough to be using a recent version of PostgreSQL, you could leverage the [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) storage to pack all your fields to a single model field. Note, though, that you'll have to implement a validation scheme by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> customer requirement.

First off, I feel your pain and wish you the best! I wish to reiterate if this wasn't the case that you should be first looking to change this as there should never be any need for hundreds of properties on a single object, it normally shows a need for an array, inheritance, or separate classes etc..

---

Going forward, you're going to need to heavily make use of `values` and `values_list` to only return the properties that you actually need from the database since performance will be severely crippled from this.

Since you can't do anything with the model, you should try to address your performance issues from the design side of things. The [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) should feature heavily in your website which will mean you'll only ever have a few values needed to be returned from the model. This way it really won't make much difference what option you choose since what is returned will be very limited.

Filter where you can, and use ordering sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could group them into a few separate models, linked by OneToOneFields to the main model. That would "namespace" your data, and namespaces are "one honking great idea".