# create object and bulk upload data into django model

Tags: python, json, django

New to django.. I have a webrequest from where I am able to get the response back in json format.
I created the view where I mapped the fields manually to each object and then used .save method by looping through the records.

**Example:**

```
for item in response:
   dataload = My_model(
      person_name = get("person_name",None)
   )
   dataload.save()
```

however this is taking a lot of time, since my data has many columns and rows around(100k)..Hence I wanted to create the object and then do a bulk load..

**Example:**

```
for item in response:
   dataobj = my_model.objects.create(
      person_name = get("person_name",None)
   )
   _models += (dataobj,)
 my_model.objects.bulk_create(_models)
```

however this is giving me an error "ORA-00001: unique constraint violated" and I believe this is due to the autogenerated id not getting created in the bulk upload process..

Can any expert please help me to fix this and load data faster to the django model.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using `bulk_create` in the wrong way. The correct way is to create a list of objects and then call `bulk_create()` like this:

```py
my_model = [My_model(person_name='some_name') for i in response]
objects = My_model.objects.bulk_create(my_model)
```

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) explain the caveats to `bulk_create()`

Comment: How can I do this with more than 70 columns/fields.. any advise?

Comment: If you have a model with more than 70 fields you could look for ways to redesign said model or use some workarounds. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287620/django-model-with-hundreds-of-fields) should help you out